# Unable to use Enterprise GitHub API to modify a repo under an organization?

Tags: curl, github, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

I am trying to make the repo `private` through `GitHub Enterprise API` by running :

`$ curl -X PATCH  $GitHubAPIurl  -u $username:$password  -d '{"name":"$d","private":"true"}'   -k`

But it returns `message: not found`

However, if I do a mild change :
`$ curl $GitHubAPIurl  -u $username:$password  -d '{"name":"$d","private":"true"}'   -k`
This will tells me that the repo already exists

So it means that my `$GitHubAPIurl` variable is correct, but why the `-X PATCH` is not working for me?

Comment: Did you try with -X POST?

Comment: @VonC, the github api doc requires me to use `PATCH` instead of `POST` to set the repo public. Plus, `-X POST` behaves the same as without `-X ` and gave me the same response.

Comment: curl doesn't work with `-X PATCH`, you need to use `--request PATCH`